# Has the Canadian government recently dismissed a net of 2,000 scientists?

Tags: economics, politics, canada

[A CBC article](http://www.cbc.ca/fifth/episodes/2013-2014/the-silence-of-the-labs) claims:

> In the past five years the federal government has dismissed more than
>   2,000 scientists, and hundreds of programs and world-renowned research
>   facilities have lost their funding.

Claims like this are being used to suggest there is an "attack on science" by the Canadian government.

> “What’s important is the scale of the assault on knowledge, and on our
>   ability to know about ourselves and to advance our understanding of
>   our world,” said James Turk, executive director of the Canadian
>   Association of University Teachers.

Were more than 2,000 scientists dismissed because their projects left unfunded? Is this just a case where the government has shifted funding to other new science programs and while 2000 positions may have been cut a similar number have been created in other projects?  Or is there some other explanation?

Comment: No matter the truth or falsehood of the claim, it would help to know how many total scientist receive such funding per year and what the usual turnover is.

Comment: Yes the usual turnover is important, perhaps it's nothing unusual to dismiss 2000 scientists a year in Canada.